# Building dynamic self join statements in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, alias

```
   Declare @alias as varchar(10)
     set @alias = 'fk2'
     insert into #Queries(Query, ExecuteOrder)
     select top 1 'delete ' + fk1.TableFrom  + ' from ' + fk1.TableFrom
     + ' join ' + @alias.TableFrom + ' on ' + fk1.TableFrom+'.'+fk1.FK_Column + ' = ' + fk2.TableFrom + '.ID' 
     + ' join ' + fk3.TableFrom + ' on ' + fk2.TableFrom+'.'+fk2.FK_Column + ' = ' + fk3.TableFrom + '.ID'
     + ' join ' + fk4.TableFrom + ' on ' + fk3.TableFrom+'.'+fk3.FK_Column + ' = ' + fk4.TableFrom + '.ID'
     + ' Where ' + fk4.TableFrom + '.' + fk4.FK_Column + ' = ' + @value
     ,@i
     from #FK fk1
     join #fk As @alias on @alias.TableFrom = fk1.TableTo
     join #fk fk3 on fk3.TableFrom = fk2.TableTo
     join #fk fk4 on fk4.TableFrom = fk3.TableTo
```

I am joining a table to itself to build a resulting query to then be executed from the temp table being inserted into.  I am currently specifying the amount of joins but would like to build them dynamically based on another integer value being passed in.  The amount of joins will correlate with this integer value.  The only problem is I need a unique Alias for each join to then be used above to build the resulting query.  Is it possible to use a dynamic Alias as to eliminate the need to hardcode the Alias for each join?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? It looks a little like a recursive deletion through a hierarchy, something you might do with a Common Table Expression (CTE).

Comment: I used a CTE to build a table holding foreign key relations within a SQL DB.  I am now joining that table to itself to build a query to delete data while adhering to the hierarchy of foreign key relationships.(I can't temporarily disable foreign key constraints)

The Table built with the CTE contains four columns: TableFrom ,    FK_Column, TableTo, RootDepth.  The root depth is used to identify the amount of joins to use to traverse the foreign key relationship hierarchy.

Comment: Have you tried executing a single `DELETE` that removes all of the related rows at once without regard to order? The table would be consistent before and after the operation. The question is would a foreign key constraint violation occur in between? Playing with a small example it seems to work, even when two rows reference each other.